# How to top-align PGFplots legend exactly flush with axis

Tags: pgfplots, positioning, legend

My goal is to top-align the legend box with the plot so that it is exactly flush with the top axis frame.

The following MWE works ok on first sight, but when looking closer, there is a small vertical offset (see image). Once seen, it cannot be unseen.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={
            legend pos=outer north east
        }
    ]
    \addplot[color=gray!50,mark=x] coordinates {
        (1,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Stuff}
    \addplot[color=gray,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Other stuff}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of unexpected offset between axis and legend box]

I know from other answers that the legend is a TikZ matrix. I'm aware of the possibility to position the legend using a coordinate (axis cs or otherwise). But even when using a hardcoded positioning like the following, the borders don't line up exactly.

```
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={
            at={(axis cs:2.6,2.1)}
        },
        ymax=2.1
    ]
```

I'm using a TeX Live 2019 installation if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. Adding`outer sep = 0pt` to your legend style might be a suitable solution.

I added some code that places the legend flush with the canvas boundary and that suggests the top of the canvas and legend are aligned when `outer sep=0pt` is added to the style.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend style={
            outer sep=0pt,
            legend pos=outer north east
        }
%        legend style={
%        anchor=north west,
%        outer sep=0pt,
%        at= {(current axis.north east)},
%}
    ]
    \addplot[color=gray!50,mark=x] coordinates {
        (1,1)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Stuff}
    \addplot[color=gray,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,2)
    };
    \addlegendentry{Other stuff}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So simple and clean! I would go as far as to say it's the perfect solution!